# Как перенести пользователей из Magento CMS с их паролями?

Tags: битрикс, magento

Необходимо перенести список пользователей из Magento  в Bitrix. Есть CSV файл со списком пользователей выгруженных из базы данных. Хотелось бы перенести пользователей со старыми паролями.  Для этого нужно получить из строки с зашифрованным паролем его хеш и дальше сохранить в Битрикс.

Загвоздка в том что я не знаю по какому принципу Magento кодирует пароли, где в строке собственно сам хеш пароля, а где дополнительные символы ( “соль”) которые можно обрезать?

Битрикс кодирует пароль в md5 а затем добавляет к полученной строке “соль”, возможно у Magento такой же принцип.  Подскажите по какому принципу в Magento cms формируются хеш паролей у пользователей.
**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**

Comment: А вы в курсе что для каждого пользователя рандомная соль в Битрикс, как скорее всего и в Magento так вы не как не передадите пароли.

Answer (score 0):

Импортируйте пользователей через API (класс CUser).

Далее делаете рассылку пользователям, уведомив о том, что им необходимо изменить пароль. И присылаете им ссылку. Они переходят пишут свой пароль и все.